# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "cte" while executing query in CTE

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

am trying to execute the following on Postgresql

[image]

and am getting

```
    ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cte"
```

click [here](http://pastebin.com/TK4BdnMu) to see my original code

Comment: show your query in code and what is `tempstockpos`

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures, post formatted text.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name next time i'll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `FROM tempstockpos WHERE .... AND tempstockpos.batchid = cte.batchid`, you must include `cte` in the `FROM` clause, like:

```
FROM tempstockpos, cte WHERE .... AND tempstockpos.batchid = cte.batchid
```

or preferably the cleaner and more readable:

```
FROM tempstockpos INNER JOIN cte ON  tempstockpos.batchid = cte.batchid WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cte` table will not be seen out of `tempstockpos` if it is not defined somewhere out of it. You do now show the whole code.

Comment: since my code is really big am not tried to update here so click [here](http://pastebin.com/TK4BdnMu) to see